# How to divide a list with 12 items in two columns with 6 items?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

[I have a list with 12 rows and I want to divide these rows in 2 columns, the first one with 6 rows and the second one with another 6 rows, someone can help me?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXkwf.png)

```html
<div class="collapse" id="divRows-@item.BandeiraAdministradoraId">
                                                @foreach (var taxa in item.TaxaBandeiraAdministradoras)
                                                {
                                                    <div style="padding-left: 100px;">
                                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => taxa.NumeroTaxas, new { @class = "text-uppercase" })
                                                        @Html.Raw("X =")
                                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => taxa.ValorTaxa, new { @class = "text-uppercase" })
                                                        @Html.Raw("%")
                                                        <br />
                                                    </div>

                                                }
                                            </div>
```

Comment: You should post sample code and add details to what you are trying to do.

Comment: I edit my question and I added the code, sorry I forget

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add number to your id to make it unique or make this id based on some of yours model data:

```
 @{int i = 0;}
 @foreach(var myItem in Model.Members)
 {
     <span id="name_@(i)">test</span>
     i++;
 }
```

Comment: I think that is because I have an If, and this confuse me!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `for-each` with a classic `for-loop` and use the indexer of it.

```
//... some code
else
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= item.TaxaBandeiraAdministradoras.Count; i++)
    {
        var taxa = item.TaxaBandeiraAdministradoras[i];
        <div id="@(i.ToString())">Example Div with Id @(i.ToString()) from Loop</div>

        <div style="padding-left: 100px;" id="demo-@item.BandeiraAdministradoraId" class="collapse">
            <div style="float: left;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => taxa.NumeroTaxas, new {@class = "text-uppercase"})
                @Html.Raw("X =")
            </div>

            <div style="float: left">
                @Html.Raw("&nbsp")
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => taxa.ValorTaxa, new {@class = "text-uppercase"})
                @Html.Raw("%")
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it! But doesn't work because my button is outside of the loop, then the variable "i" doesn't work because that one is not a global variable...I don't know what I have to do in this case...

Comment: What should the button do? One button for `n` entries?

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo-@item.BandeiraAdministradoraId">Detalhes</button>

Comment: This is my button

Comment: Sorry for my english ok? I'm brazillian

Comment:  Which Id should the button contain? Should there a button for each Item?

Comment: Hi Smartis, thank u for your attention, I can resolve my problem!